# JavaScript DOM coding - 'undefined' error

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I am having problem with this error:

> ***'undefined' is null or not an object'***

Can you please have a look and let me know. In my coding, I want to have simple DOM JavaScript code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script>
    init();
    function init()
    {
        getElementByTabIndex("4", "submit")[0].addEventListener("click", Verify, false);
    }
    function Verify() {
        alert('done');  
        // all verification code will be here...
    }
    function getElementByTabIndex(index, type, node)
    {
        if (!node)
        { 
            node = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; 
        } 

        var a = [];
        els = node.getElementsByTagName('*'); 
        for (var i = 0, j = els.length; i < j; i++) 
        { 
            if (els[i].tabIndex == index && els[i].type == type)
            { 
                a.push(els[i]);
            } 
        } 
    return a; 
}

</script>
<body>
<input type="email" id="email" /><input type="password" id="pass" /> <label class="Login" for="login"><input value="Log In" tabindex="4" type="submit" id="login"></label>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: When do you get the error? How do you reproduce it? On what line does it occur?

Comment: LINE 24 : getElementByTabIndex("4", "submit") 0].addEventListener("click", Verify, false);

In IE, you can see JavaScript error in status bar or in Safari - the  error show as 'TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'node.getElementsByTagName')' in line 24.

Comment: it looks fine to me. I tested it in google Chrome (http://jsfiddle.net/DavidLaberge/gdgFS/2/). What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox and Google Chrome works i guess. but in Safari and IE is giving me that errors.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using classic javascript? Could you use jQuery? in that case it would be cross browser and easier for you.

Comment: I have to use classic javascript, Because I am doing for extension for Safari,  And I am not sure JQuery will work or not in Extension.. So I would like to code only with Classic javascipt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to move you code at bottom or  call `init()`  after body is loaded.

**Reason:** you are trying to get elements even before they exists.

**Eg** :

```
<head>
   <script>
      var elm= document.getElementById('id');

      //this will be always undefied, as trying to read element even before they exist
   </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='foo'></div>

   <script>
      var elm= document.getElementById('id');

      //this wont be undefined 
   </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks it works in simple HTML, i am trying to use in my extension now. I will let you know how it comes out in extension.

Answer (score 0):

You call:

```
if (!node) { 
    node = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; 
}
```

But your script runs before the DOM has finished loading, and so the `body` tag does not exist.

So `node` is `undefined`, and when you attempt the following, you get your error:

```
node.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

Run `init()` on document load, instead of immediately.

---

<sup>**PS.** jsfiddle and Firebug allowed me to debug this very quickly.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

'body' isn't available to javascript at the time you are trying to call init().

call your init method when the dom has finished loading, like so:

```
window.onload = function (){
    init();
}
```

note that in order to make this work across browsers (if you plan on using it outside your planned Safari extention) you will have to do some extra work. more info: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domready.shtml